# ReactJS FullCalendar won't load events into calendar

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

Im grabbing the events dynamically from my backend API however when I make the call `compoentWillMount()` its as if the calendar is loading first and not getting the events so its not loading/displaying the events on the calendar. I keep looking through the docs and trying different solutions and cant get anything to succeed. My components code:

```
import React from "react";
import Tooltip from "tooltip.js";
import moment from 'moment';

import ErrorBoundary from "../Utils/ErrorBoundary";

import FullCalendar from "@fullcalendar/react";
import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid";
import interactionPlugin from "@fullcalendar/interaction";


import "@fullcalendar/core/main.css";
import "@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css";

class ChoreCalendar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      chores: [],
      events: []
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/chores')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      this.setState({ chores: data })

      data.data.forEach(chore => {
        this.state.events.push({
          title: chore.title,
          date: moment(chore.dueDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
          color: "green",
          textColor: "white"
        })
      });
    })
    .catch(console.log)
  }

  eventRender(info) {
    var tooltip = new Tooltip(info.el, {
      title: info.event.extendedProps.title,
      placement: "top",
      trigger: "click",
      container: "body"
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ibox">
        <div className="ibox-content">
          <ErrorBoundary>
            <FullCalendar
              id="fullCalendar"
              defaultView="dayGridMonth"
              plugins={[dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
              events={this.state.events}
              eventRender={this.eventRender}
              schedulerLicenseKey="GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source"
            />
          </ErrorBoundary>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ChoreCalendar;
```

All I'm currently trying to do is dynamically grab the events and then load them into the calendar and have them show.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just write `events={"http://localhost:8080/api/chores"}` (as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed). Or perhaps it should be  `events="http://localhost:8080/api/chores"`  - I'm not quite sure of the syntax in the React version. But the point is, I don't see any great need for this external loading process...why not let fullCalendar handle it for you? The only issue I can foresee is because your date field is named incorrectly, but you can fix that server-side, or via [eventDataTransform](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDataTransform)

Comment: P.S. It's unclear to what extent you've debugged your current code - you haven't spoken about whether you're seeing any network or script errors, or issues with asynchronous timings, which might prevent fullCalendar from loading the events, but one thing i can see which is definitely an issue is, again, the name of your date field. `date: moment(chore.dueDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD")` needs to be `start: moment(chore.dueDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD")` . As per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing, fullCalendar doesn't recognise any field called "date", it must be "start" (and optionally "end")

Answer (score 0):

Add initialEvent prop in FullCalender Tag and assign it some state with initial values.